# ionic- Minimizing the app in ios

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to minimize the app. While pressing home button, the foreground app is going to background. While launching the app, the background operation should perform in foreground with corresponding page where i put the app in background. In my case, while launching the app after minimize, it navigates to login screen.

Answer (score -1):

Add `Application does not run in background` in info.plist and set its value NO

[image]

Comment: Thanks fr ur help... but It's not working in my case.. Still facing the same iisue....